# Oracle to SQL Server conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration

I have a particular condition in oracle which I am trying to run in MS SQL Server, but having issues..

Here is the code...

```
select a.*,b.*
from a
  left join b on a.id = b.id
  and (a.id,b.name) in
        ( select distinct id,name
          from master where record = 'Active')
```

I am getting the error in line 3 where it says:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ','.

Pls help

Comment: Oracle or SQL-Server? I think on Oracle this query should work.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is useless. It only decreases the performance.

Comment: To SQL server from oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite that into an `EXISTS` condition:

```
select a.*,b.*
from a
  left join b on a.id = b.id
  and exists (select * 
              from master m
              where m.record = 'Active'
                and m.id = a.id 
                and m.name = b.name)
```

Comment: Just a note, `IN (...)` behaves different than `EXIST` for NULL values (at least in Oracle). Since query uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it implies that `b.name` might be NULL.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I don't think that makes a difference. The `IN` clause also uses `=` to compare column values. So e.g. `(42, null) IN (....)` where the sub-select returns a NULL value would not be included as well, just as with the `exists` solution

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: see here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab04b19c4fa985f361455184a39fd73b

Answer (score 0):

You can't write like this `(a.id,b.name)`

```
select a.*,b.*
from a
  left join b on a.id = b.id
  and a.id in
        ( select distinct id
          from master where record = 'Active')
  and b.name in ( select distinct name
          from master where record = 'Active')
```

Comment: Two expression in `sub-query`  ??

Comment: Unrelated id and name conditions?!?

Comment: @jarlh How is id and name conditions unrelated??

Comment: The master table may contain an Active row, and another id row.